# Connection to Snowflake Database with Node Continually Terminates for Website

Tags: node.js, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

What is the best/correct way to connect to a snowflake database using Node? ie where do I put the connection info?  Do I ever destroy the connection?  How do I avoid having a terminated connection error?

I'm building a website using Node for the backend and Snowflake for the database.  After an unknown period of time, usually after several hours of inactivity (ie late at night/early morning), the website doesn't load and all I get is the error: "Unable to perform operation using terminated connection".  The only way I fix this is by restarting the server, which fixes the error immediately.  Note that this error is what you get if the connection DNE as well ie was never connected and then terminated.

I have tried reaching out to SF support, they said to never disconnect/destroy the connection (which fixed the first problem of things never connecting). Didn't solve the problem.

I tried moving the connection code (below) to the router

```
var snowflake = require('snowflake-sdk');

// Create a Connection object that we can use later to connect.
var connection = snowflake.createConnection( {
    account: process.env.ACCOUNT,
    username: process.env.SFUSER,
    password: process.env.SNOWFLAKEPW,
    database: process.env.SNOWFLAKEDB,
    warehouse: process.env.SNOWFLAKEWH
    }
);

connection.connect();
```

however, I couldn't figure out how to make connection a global var to pass to the router b/c I have a routes file with multiple queries in sequence.  I have multiple route files with multiple routes each. My routers set up like this

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const controller= require('../snowflake/controller.js')
const controller2= require('../snowflake/controller2.js')

router.get('/submitted', controller.query1, controller.query2, controller2.query3, controller.loadView)

module.exports = router
```

I also tried moving the connection info to the top of each of the controller files because connection was able to become a global var, but I continue to get the terminated connection error.

My only other guess is to do something like this before each route, but if a user loads multiple pages, does that create the same error where multiple connections are being made?

```
router.get('/submitted', SFcontroller.snowflakeConnect, controller.query1, controller.query2, controller2.query3, SFcontroller.snowflakeDestroy, controller.loadView)
```

The snowflake docs are sparse and just provide the syntax and nothing about best practices.  Would love to see some example of working code

Comment: Can you do a short query of like SELECT 1 to prevent the inactivity? I know that's not ideal, but perhaps would workaround.

Comment: @SuzyLockwood i havent tried this yet, and am trying to avoid having to make random queries because as you said, far from ideal.  i havent had this issue with redshift or postgresql so i dont know if it's an issue of the node driver just being limited or syntax...even knowing there's soln would be nice so i can stop looking

Comment: @SuzyLockwood i meant knowing there's *no soln.  sorry, couldnt edit.

Comment: It looks like Node has the client_session_keep_alive parameter supported now. Would you give that a try to see if it helps?  https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-nodejs/issues/30

Comment: @SuzyLockwood I tried that 2 days ago and the same issue happened the next day and today...I included it like this:  
`var snowflake = require('snowflake-sdk');
snowflake.configure({logLevel: 'trace', clientSessionKeepAlive: true})
`

Comment: Well, I would think that should work as long as you're using a later version of the connector that supports the parameter.  Can you also test using an ALTER SESSION statement to change the parameter for the session? Just in case snowflake.configure is not picking it up.

Comment: @user3768258 This is because you need to set this flag as a connection option, not a configuration option: `snowflake.createConnection({account:..., username: ..., password: ..., clientSessionKeepAlive: true});`